# retrofit 1.9.0, Post request, what am I missing

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I'm trying to make multipart requset but whatever I do I get same error. I think I'm missing something, please point it out to me. This is all the code about the request:
1. Interface class

```
public interface ApiInterface{
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/ads")
retrofit.client.Response updateProfileWithImage(
        @Part("user_token") TypedString ut,
        @Part("apikey") TypedString ke,
        @Part("title") TypedString ti,
        @Part("description") TypedString de,
        @Part("id_location") TypedString lo,
        @Part("id_category") TypedString ca,
        @Part("phone") TypedString ph,
        @Part("price") TypedString pr,
        @PartMap Map<String,TypedFile> Files
);

}
```

2. OnCreate activity . image path in form of /sdcard/.....

   ```
   RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                       .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                       .setEndpoint("http://website.com")
                       .build();
               ApiInterface apiInterface = adapter.create(ApiInterface.class);

               TypedString ut = new TypedString(utoken);
               TypedString ke = new TypedString(apikey);
               TypedString ti = new TypedString(tite);
               TypedString de = new TypedString(dese);
               TypedString lo = new TypedString(idloc);
               TypedString ca = new TypedString(idcat);
               TypedString ph = new TypedString(phono);
               TypedString pr = new TypedString(prici);

               Map<String, TypedFile> files = new HashMap<String, TypedFile>();
               files.put("image", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(fii)));
                 //here i get retrofiterror talking about rest adapter
               retrofit.client.Response response = apiInterface.updateProfileWithImage(ut, ke, ti, de, lo, ca, ph, pr, files);
   ```

I'm about to die from this I have suffered a lot, please help me

UPDATE: 
error solved by running the code in new thread, but still the image is not uploaded, please help. This is who to new thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                       //but all retrofit code here
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: 12-27 09:27:18.278 E/AndroidRuntime(19112):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include exception stacktrace into your question. How is /api/v1/ads declared on backend? What http response is send? Include it also into your question (use Edit button).

Comment: thanks, I didnt understand you what is not clear

Comment: please read the update can you help me